# What's the correct way of using case in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error "Incorrect syntax near '<'.". What's the correct way of using case, comparison operator in where clause?

Here is my Sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(AL.PKAPPLICATIONID) FROM APPLICATIONLOGO AL 
LEFT JOIN THIRDPARTYSESSIONKEY TSK ON AL.PKAPPLICATIONID = TSK.APPLICATIONSOURCEID WHERE
CASE WHEN TSK.CREATEDON IS  NULL 
THEN TSK.CREATEDON < GETDATE()
ELSE 1=1
END
```

Comment: Please explain the condition more fully.

Comment: This logic doesn't make sense.  It is equivalent to `tsk.CreatedOn is not null`.  The comparison never gets executed because the `case` statement is probably the inverse of the logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN TSK.CREATEDON IS  NULL THEN TSK.CREATEDON < GETDATE() ELSE 1=1
      END
```

I assume you mean `IS NOT NULL`; otherwise the logic doesn't make much sense.

In general, the best way to use `case` in a `where` clause is to avoid it.  The following is easier to read and probably what you intend:

```
WHERE TSK.CREATEDON IS NULL OR TSK.CREATEDON < GETDATE()
```

The original logic for your version is simply:

```
WHERE TSK.CREATEDON IS NOT NULL
```

And, the specific answer to your question is that a `case` statement returns a value and a boolean result is not a value.  So, the following does not work:

```
where (case when c = 'a' then a = b else c = b end)
```

The following does:

```
where (case when c = 'a' then a else c end) = b
```

But as I say, better to just use the basic logical operators in most cases.

Comment: yes i missed "not" there. It's actually "is not null". My requirement was to get rows where created is not current time.

Answer (score 3):

Use  an `OR`:

```
SELECT Count(AL.Pkapplicationid) 
FROM   APPLICATIONLOGO AL 
       LEFT JOIN THIRDPARTYSESSIONKEY TSK 
              ON AL.Pkapplicationid = TSK.Applicationsourceid 
WHERE TSK.Createdon IS NULL  
  OR  TSK.Createdon < Getdate()
```

I assume that this is the actual logic since yours makes not sense:

```
WHEN TSK.Createdon IS NULL THEN TSK.Createdon < Getdate()
```

or do you actually want to use a different column in case `Createdon IS NULL`?

Then you could use `COALESCE` / `ISNULL`:

```
WHERE COALESCE(TSK.Createdon, TSK.OtherColumn) < Getdate()
```

Comment: I think so too, it should read `IS NOT NULL` in the question - I was trying to make sense of it too!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get all records with CREATEDON date as yesterday and older and should include columns where CREATEDON  is NULL. If that's the case, the below query will work

```
SELECT COUNT(AL.PKAPPLICATIONID)
FROM APPLICATIONLOGO AS AL
    LEFT JOIN THIRDPARTYSESSIONKEY AS TSK
    ON AL.PKAPPLICATIONID = TSK.APPLICATIONSOURCEID
WHERE CAST(ISNULL(TSK.CREATEDON,GETDATE()-1) AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```